# Disable parquet metadata summary in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a spark job (for 1.4.1) receiving a stream of kafka events.
I would like to save them continuously as parquet on tachyon.

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)

lines.window(Seconds(1), Seconds(1)).foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
  if (rdd.count() > 0) {
    val mil = time.floor(Duration(86400000)).milliseconds
    hiveContext.read.json(rdd).toDF().write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(s"tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted5$mil")
    hiveContext.sql(s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persisted5$mil USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet OPTIONS ( path 'tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted5$mil')")
  }
}
```

however I see that as time goes on, on every parquet write, spark goes through each 1 sec parquet parts, which get slower and slower

```
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-db03b24d-6f98-4b5d-bb40-530f35b82633.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-3a7857e2-0435-4ee0-ab2c-6d40224f8842.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-47ff2ac1-da00-4473-b3f7-52640014bc5b.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-61625436-7353-4b1e-bb8d-e8afad3a582e.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-e711aa9a-9bf5-41d5-8523-f5edafa69626.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-4e0cca38-cf75-4771-8965-20a30c863100.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-d1510ed4-2c99-43e2-b3d1-38d3d54e626d.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-022d1918-392d-433f-a7f4-074e46b4460f.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-cf71f5d2-ba0e-4729-9aa1-41dad5d1d08f.gz.parquet, 65536)
15/08/22 22:04:05 INFO : open(tachyon://192.168.1.12:19998/persisted51440201600000/part-r-00000-ce990b1e-82cc-4feb-a162-ac3ddc275609.gz.parquet, 65536)
```

I came to the conclusion that this is due to the update of summary data, I believe spark do not make use of them. so I would like to disable it

[parquet sources](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/fa8957d7939b59e8d391fa17000b34e865de015d/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputCommitter.java) shows that I should be able to set "parquet.enable.summary-metadata" to false.

now, I have tried setting it like this, right after creating hiveContext

```
hiveContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", false)
hiveContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("parquet.metadata.read.parallelism", 10)
```

but without success, I also still get logs showing a parallelism of 5 (default).

What is the correct way to disable summary data in spark with parquet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

setting "parquet.enable.summary-metadata" as text ("false" and not false) seems to work for us.

By the way Spark does use the _common_metadata file (we copy that over manually for repetitive jobs)

Comment: If I disable shemaMerging, are the metadata still used? seems to work ok with beeline.

Comment: in Spark 1.3 no and in 1.4.1 it still looks for the _common_metadata (perhaps that a bug)

Comment: It seems to fallback to read the part footer when I refresh if the metadata is missing. But works (still slowly though, essentially moved the problem from the insert to the refresh)

Comment: if you disable metadata while writing small batches how do you generate them manually later on ?

Comment: In later Spark version we didn't find this a problem and reenabled this - but anyway when we didn't generate metadata we copied over the basic metadata from previous jobs (same output structure...)

Comment: didn't the schema change overtime ? I am finding it hard to generate common_metadata https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17527

Comment: Schema did change and we wrote something that handled that by applying transformations on read  - we as I mentioned in the previous comment we didn't find we need disable meta data creation in newer spark versions

Answer (score 15):

Spark 2.0 doesn't save metadata summaries by default any more, see [SPARK-15719](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15719).

If you are working with data hosted in S3, you *may* still find parquet performance hit by parquet itself trying to scan the tail of all objects to check their schemas. That can be disabled explicitly

```
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "false")
```

Comment: "Since schema merging is a relatively expensive operation, and is not a necessity in most cases, we turned it off by default starting from 1.5.0" -- [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging)