# how to speed up saving partitioned data with only one partition?

Tags: apache-spark

The spark data saving operation is quite slow if:

the dataframe `df` partitioned by date (year, month, day), `df` contains data from exactly one day, say 2019-02-14.

If I save the `df` by:

```
df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").parquet("/path/")
```

It will be slow due to all data belong to one partition, which is processed by one task (??).

If saving `df` with explicit partition path:

```
df.write.parquet("/path/year=2019/month=02/day=14/")
```

It works well, but it will create the _metadata, _common_metadata, _SUCCESS files in `"/path/year=2019/month=02/day=14/"`
in stead of `"/path/"`. Drop partition columns are required to keep same fields as using method `partitionBy`.

So, how to speed up saving data with only one partition without changing metadata files location, which can be updated in each OP.

Is it safe to use explicit partition path instead of using `partitionBy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable parquet metadata summary in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160926/disable-parquet-metadata-summary-in-spark)

Comment: Here the issue is caused by data with only one partition (only one day), while the link you posted is related to summary metadata slowing down the process.